# Detecting and diagnosing workers silently crashing

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm running Celery 2 using daemonizing - http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html with RabbitMQ. 
From time to time silent crash happens, the only thing i see in celeryd.log:

```
[2010-12-24 14:14:31,323: INFO/PoolWorker-1414] process shutting down
[2010-12-24 14:14:31,323: INFO/PoolWorker-1414] process exiting with exitcode 0
[2010-12-24 14:14:31,331: INFO/PoolWorker-1415] child process calling self.run()
[2010-12-24 14:14:48,673: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: airsale.search.xxx.get_search_results[01bf5d36-7c0e-4f8a-af69-750ef1b24abc]
[2010-12-24 14:14:48,761: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: airsale.search.xxx.get_search_results[2d5f9952-d493-4de4-9752-0eee1776147d]
[2010-12-24 14:14:48,861: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: airsale.search.xxx.get_search_results[0c77c1ec-df6c-4e34-875c-44909fbf8b9f]
[2010-12-24 14:14:48,961: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: airsale.search.xxx.get_search_results[3d83dd54-0be8-4cf9-9cd6-81e070d97170]
[2010-12-24 14:14:49,061: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: airsale.search.xxx.get_search_results[2dd29e70-e085-4fd1-a7ef-12d06b21644c]
..........
```

Then - only "Got task from broker" without any task processing.

`ps -C celeryd` shows - that celery nodes are running.

If i do : `/etc/init.d/celeryd restart` - number of celeryd processes doubles. Seems that old processes are uncontrolled by daemon any more.

1. How to detect - why task processing is not performed, even if task is received from broker?
2. Why old celeryd processes are not killed by `/etc/init.d/celeryd restart`?

Comment: It says PoolWorker-1415, which means 1415 processes must have been started (and maybe stopped later).  How many workers have you configured?  What is the celery related configuration settings?  Also, does it work if not running daemonized?

Answer (score 1):

Queue workers are stalled, so the main solution to this is to adjust a the task time limit for each task, in a way to restart the worker when the tasks exceed this time.

Add to your task the following

```
from celery.decorators import task
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded


@task()
def mytask():
    try:
        do something()
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        clean something()
```

in your settings.py add the following

```
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 #sec
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 30 #sec
```

Comment: not sure about that, i already have hard time limit for tasks, so problem should be somewhere else